# ArrayList type variable assigned to another is passed as reference in Android Java

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am developing an Android project. First of all, I am not a Java developer. Now I want to know something in about Java programming, especially about ArrayList.

Here is my code:

```
        ArrayList<Bitmap> previewBitmaps = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
        //initialize values - total 3 elements
        previewBitmaps.remove(2);
        ArrayList<Bitmap> temp = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
        temp = previewBitmaps;
        previewBitmaps.removeAll(previewBitmaps);
        //here temp size become zero because previewBitmaps cleared
```

As you can see in the above code, I remove an item from previewBitmaps, then I assigned the rest 2 items to temp. So size of temp will be 2. Then I clear previewBitmaps. So previewBitmaps size become 0. But the problem is temp size also become 0. Why?

Actually temp size should be 2. Right? What I am not clear is whether it is assigned as reference variable in C? Why? How can I clear that reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `temp = previewBitmaps;` you assign the memory address of your `previewBitmaps` ArrayList to `temp`. Meaning that they both point to the same memory address. Every action you perform to one will apply to both cause they point to the same Object in memory.

If you want to make a new copy of the ArrayList you could use this:
`temp = new ArrayList(previewBitmaps);`

Comment: Oh thank you. But in C#, temp = previewBitmaps; will not point to the same memory address. Right?

Comment: I dont know about C# but i think its more likely to point to the same memory address as well.

Comment: I know about c# and this is the same with java there ;)

Comment: Yeah i thought so.

Answer (score 1):

Becuase when you assign one non-primitive object to another one actually java makes both those variables point to one place in memory. When you change the data in memory both these variables will be affected .

Only primitive type dont act like this for example for an int variable such a thing wont happen but for all non-primitive types its like this ;)

Primitive types are int, float, char, ...

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is basically: dont try to learn java programming and android at the same time.

Example:

```
ArrayList<Bitmap> previewBitmaps = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
```

creates a new **empty** map. So does:

```
ArrayList<Bitmap> temp = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
```

but your next line

```
temp = previewBitmaps;
```

**throws** away the list you created in the previous step. Gone. What is the point of creating a new list to throw it away afterwards?!

What happens is that the two variables *previewBitmaps* and *temp* both point to the **same** reference. So you are not manipulating two different lists, but only **one** list afterwards.

If your idea was to create a "temp" copy of the first list; you could be doing

```
List<Bitmap> temp = new ArrayList<>(previewBitmps);
```

instead (the above creates a *new* list containing all elements of the other list).

And please note: as **types** you should prefer to use the more abstract interfaces, such as *List*. You only use the concrete type (like *ArrayList* when creating objects); afterwards you should only access objects using the List interface.

Thus: focus on such java basics first! Otherwise your experience with Android will be very short and frustrating. As you will run from one problem into the next one. Learn to crawl before you try to run.

Answer (score 0):

For you to set the values of previewBitmaps to temp.
You might wanna use temp.addAll(previewBitmaps);

Answer (score 0):

previewBitmaps is a reference variables that points to an object. Now when you remove the item at position 2, the object(List) becomes of size 2.
Now when you write `ArrayList<Bitmap> temp = new ArrayList<Bitmap>()` , it creates a new object in heap memory and a reference variable temp points to that new object.
Then you call `temp = previewBitmaps` . Now temp points to the same object previewBitmaps  is pointing at. Therefore, when you call

```
previewBitmaps.removeAll(previewBitmaps);
```

it removes all the items from the object to which both the reference variables are pointing at i.e previewBitmaps  and temp .

Answer (score 0):

This is happening as you are assigning two references to same object.
You need to make a deep clone of the current ArrayList instead of shallow.

`for(Bitmap b: previewBitmaps){
  temp.add(b.clone())
  }`

Doing `temp = previewBitmaps.clone()` won't help as it will create a new `ArrayList` but both list will be pointing to same objects inside. This is known as shallow clone.